# Conversão de array para array bidimensional utilizando parâmetro

Tags: java, array, array-multidimensional

Estou com uma dúvida referente a conversão de vetores (array) para vetores bidimensionais.

Preciso ler uma string e separar as colunas quando encontra-se um espaço em branco. Fiz isso utilizando o método `split()` e já está ok. Porém, ao encontrar vírgula, deve ser criada uma nova linha.

Exemplo:

```
1 2, 3 4, 5 6:

[1, 2,
3, 4,
5, 6]
```

Alguma dica de como fazer essa conversão utilizando algum parâmetro?

Segue código que fiz até agora:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String vetorEnt;
    System.out.println("Informe a primeira matriz, com base no seguinte exemplo:");
    vetorEnt = scan.nextLine();
    String[] vetor1 = vetorEnt.split(",");
    System.out.println("Vetor quebrado" + Arrays.toString(vetor1));

    String[][] matriz1 = new String[vetor1.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
      matriz1[i] = vetor1[i].split("\\s");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < matriz1[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(matriz1[i][j] + "");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println(matriz1.length);
    System.out.println(vetor1.length);
  }
```

O que ocorre: preciso ler uma string e transformar a mesma em uma matriz. O parâmetro para quebra de coluna é um espaço, e para quebra de linha é uma vírgula. Então, se caso eu ler a string:

```
A B C, E F G
```

A nova matriz precisa armazenar:

```
|A|B|C|,

|E|F|G|. -> Matriz 2x3
```

Preciso obter esses dados pois preciso ler 2 matrizes e calcular a multiplicação das mesmas, mas, infelizmente, não estou conseguindo prosseguir.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione o que já fez até agora, assim facilita sugerir algo ja baseado no seu codigo.

Comment: Pronto, já fiz a alteração!